# Synonym of déjà vu that fits the scenario described here

Tags: synonyms

déjà vu is a French word, & deja vu is its borrowed version.

Is there a synonym for it in English that I can use in the conversation given below?

(For instance 'per se' is Latin, but it has many one-word synonyms. )

Please consider this conversation

"It can't be Deja vu, you have never met the man before," he yelled at me

"It was Deja vu. I swear it! I have definitely met him before. From the moment I saw him, I knew he was going to attack! " I exclaimed as the felling chilled my gut.

"Technically speaking, it is called ____" he shouted

"Really? Am I going mad? Is my mind tricking me?'

"I actually don't know" he smiled.

Comment: Déjà vu is an English word, borrowed from French. You'll find it in the OED. [I just mistakenly posted this comment as an answer and it doesn't seem to have deleted...]

Comment: Presumably we use the French term because it expresses something there isn't a word for in English.

Comment: In what context? Please construct an example sentence and leave a gap for the word you want to put in its place.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Déjà vu" is two words, I understand, but I am asking for one-word synonym

Comment: The term "déjà vu" was loaned to English because there is no one word equivalent, that's why the French term was assimilated. It is now "English", the meanings of "pseudomemory", "familiarity", and "cliche" are similar but they are not synonymous. As a writer you could simply describe the scene and the resulting emotions and let your readers infer the rest: [*Show, don't tell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell).

Comment: "As a writer, I have to use synonyms to eradicate the repetition of the same words." Absolutely wrong. It's good to use synonyms, but you can't use synonyms if none exist, and repeating a word is not an unpardonable flaw.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for clarifying, this is what my mentor told me at the time of training.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple senses of *déjà vu*:

> **1a :** the illusion of remembering scenes and events when experienced for the first time
>   **1b :** a feeling that one has seen or heard something before
>   **2 :** something overly or unpleasantly familiar
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0%20vu)</sub>

---

For **1a**, consider ***pseudomemory***:

> *False memory syndrome*, also called *recovered memory*, ***pseudomemory***, and *memory distortion*, [is] the experience, usually in the context of adult psychotherapy, of seeming to remember events that never actually occurred.
>   <sub>[Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/false-memory-syndrome)</sub>

---

For **1b**, consider ***familiarity***:

> **1a :** the quality or state of being familiar
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/familiarity)</sub>

---

For **2**, consider ***cliché***:

> **3 :** something (such as a menu item) that has become overly familiar or commonplace
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clich%C3%A9)</sub>

Comment: 1a is the answer for me...:)